# How to disable SIM card PIN code programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, sim-card, pin-code

In Android how do I disable SIM card PIN code programmatically?

Many other posts ask how to unlock/set/reset SIM card PIN code. However, I want to disable it.

[image]

The option is in 'Settings' -> 'Security' -> 'Set up SIM card lock'

Comment: Any code to share with what you tried so far?

Comment: @lenz I spend all day in https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base but find nothing... there is only one related method called 'isSimPinEnabled' in TelephonyManager.java